# Pointing at array

Tags: c++

There is such code:

```
int tab[14][2];
int (*wskk)[2] = tab; // &tab makes error

int tab2[2];
wskk = &tab2; // tab2 makes error
```

Why is it possible to use one pointer to point at two arrays of different dimensions?

Comment: What do you mean by *arrays of different type*?

Comment: tab is int[14][2], and tab2 is int[2]

Comment: I think he's referring to different dimensions

Comment: In C/C++, a pointer does not really point to an array; it points to an element inside the array.  In this case, the first element.

Comment: @Nemo: What about pointers to arrays?

Comment: Why would wskk = &tab2 cause an error? Aren't they both of type int[2]?

Comment: @Tom: I suppose he meant `tab2 makes error`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand what's going on you must be familiar with a few key-concepts:

- a multidimensional array is an array of arrays;
- the name of an array decays to a pointer to its first element;
- the type of `wskk` is "pointer to an array of 2 `int`s".

Thus, if you write `tab` you're getting a pointer to the first element of `tab`, which is its first row; the row has type `int[2]`, so a pointer to it has type `int (*)[2]`, which is exactly the type of your pointer. Because of this you can assign `tab` to `wskk`, which will now point to the first row of `tab`.

You *can't* assign `&tab` to it, because that yields you a pointer to the whole multidimensional array, which is of type `int (*)[14][2]`.

As for the second piece, it's even simpler: `tab2` is an array of two `int`s, so its type is `int[2]`. If you get a pointer to it via the `&` operator, you get a `int (*)[2]`, which is the type of your pointer. Actually, it makes sense: `tab2` and a row of `tab` are effectively the same stuff (an array of 2 `int`s).

You *can't* assign `tab2` to it because `tab2` decays to a pointer to its first element, i.e. an `int *`.

Answer (score 4):

Make the array-to-pointer conversion explicit, it may become more clear:

```
int tab[14][2];
int (*wskk)[2] = &tab[0]; // point at tab[0], which has type array of 2 int

int tab2[2];
wskk = &tab2;              // point at tab2, which has type array of 2 int
```

See also: [How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)