# 2d char array and char pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I have an array of `char`s, and it is initialized using a nested `for` loop.

How do I access each element of the array such as `a[i][j]` using a `char` pointer?

I have tried `* (* (p+i)+j)` which gives me a unary error. I have also tried the following:

```
char a[maxr][maxc];
char *p = 0;
p = &a[0][0];
int i,j;
for (i = 0; i < r-1; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < c-2; j++){
         while (*p != '\0'){
               *p = 'Y';
               p++;
         }
    }
}
```

If i do:

```
char a[maxr][maxc];
    char *p = 0;
    p = &a[0][0];
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < r-1; i++){
          p = p+i;  
        for (j = 0; j < c-2; j++){
            p = p+j;
             while (*p != '\0'){
                   *p = 'Y';
                   p++;
             }
        }
    }
```

This seems to traverse the array; however, I am not quite sure if it is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Without knowing the type of `a` this is not possible to answer accurately. An array of arrays vs an array of pointers will have different answers. Update the question to include the declaration of `a` please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointing at array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613584/pointing-at-array)

Comment: @WhozCraig `a` is there ... The markdown was failing but I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `a` is defined as `char *a[m]` (`m > i`)

To get the value of `a[i][j]`, you've got to use something like,

```
char ** p = a;
```

and

```
*(*(p + i) + j)
```

provided, `i` and `j` a are *valid* index locations.

Answer (score 0):

with r is total row,
try this:

```
*(p+i*r +j)
```